# Important questions to ask yourself when writing research paper

Tags: research-process, research-topic

I remember I read somewhere four (at least I think it was four) important questions to ask yourself when writing research paper, such as "What is the problem?", "Why is that important?", etc.

These questions were named after some guy or something whose name I don't remember. Please help me remember the name.

Comment: A google could be worth trying - you should recognize the name - we have little chance...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not exactly what you're after but it's commonly recommended to answer the three standard questions what-why-how:

- **What is it?** What is the object of the work and what is the context? Are there any similar questions already solved or studied in the literature?  How does your goal/question differ from existing works?
- **Why does it matter?** What are the motivations for doing this work? What problem does it solve (or contribute to solve)? what use cases does it apply to?
- **How?** Which method can be used? Why this method in particular? What are the potential limitations of this approach?